# while loop same word

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with my code. It's supposed to print the words entered by the user as a sentence unless the user enters the word "finish" or the same word twice. Right now it will not end the loop if the same word is entered twice despite the `if word == word:` command which I thought would do the trick, how could I improve?

```py
sentence = " "
while True: 
    word = input("Please enter your word:")
    if word == "finish":
        break
    if word == word:
        break
   sentence += word + " "
 
print(sentence)
```

Comment: You will need a temporary variable to hold previous value.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for you would be to use a list and only add the inputs to said list if the word is not equal to finish or the last element of the list itself.

Once the loop breaks, join the list and print it.

```
sentence = [""]
while True: 
    word = str(input("Please enter your word:"))
    if word != "finish" and word != sentence[-1]:
        sentence.append(word)
    else: break

sentence = ' '.join(sentence[1:])
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're asking you're code to stop the loop only if the input it's exactly the input word, instead of asking it to stop if it contains already contains that word.

This should work:

```
sentence = " "
while True:
    userInput = input("Please enter your word:")
    if userInput == 'finish' or userInput in sentence:
        break
    sentence = sentence + " " + userInput

print(sentence)
```

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I've just corrected the code and know it works :) @quamrana

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
sentence = " "
word_copy = None

while True: 
    word = input("Please enter your word:")
    if word == "finish":
        break
    if word_copy == word:
        break
    word_copy = word
    sentence += word + " "
 
print(sentence)
```

In your code you are checking (word==word) which will be always true.
I hope it is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Right now word == word will always be True. You should use a `prevWord` variable to store the last word at the end of each loop, then compare `prevWord` and current word like `prevWord == word`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the word entered to the last word entered, you could do that by getting the last word in sentence.

```
sentence = ""

while True: 
    word = input("Please enter your word:")
    if word == "finish":
        break
    if [word] == sentence.split(' ')[:-1]:
        break
    sentence += word + " "
    
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that out, but seems like I'm a bit late):

```
sentence = []
temp = None
while True:
    word = input("Please enter your word:")
    if word == 'finish' or word == temp:
        break
    temp = word
    sentence.append(word)

print(' '.join(sentence))
```

here's solution with unique words as well, if same word written, loop breaks:

```
sentence = []
while True:
    word = input("Please enter your word:")
    if word == 'finish' or word in sentence:
        break
    sentence.append(word)

print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all the words before in a list:

```
sentence = ""
words = []
while True:
word = input("Please enter your word: ")
if word == "finish":
    break
# this checks if the word is already in the word list
elif word in words:
    break
    else:
        # append the word to the word list
        words.append(word)
        sentence = sentence + word
```

That should work :)
The problem of your code is, `word` is changed every time your program runs the `while`-loop, because it can only have one value.